# Add extra values to the the document in JSON API Response

Tags: json

I like to respond a Json like this

```
'{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'
```

How is this possible with thos class:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.2-dev/libraries/src/MVC/View/JsonApiView.php

It looks as I only can have link, data and jsonapi at the first Level of the JsonResponse.

Comment: Does JSON:API even allow that? Maybe you need generic JSON output instead?

Comment: Thank you. You are right, this not allowed: https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level . How is the recommanded way to realise an output like this in Joomla? Is there an example?

Comment: Do you need this in the API application? Or in site/administrator?

Comment: I have not been able to solve this in the api yet either. I have used the view to a component like here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/4.2-dev/administrator/components/com_admin/src/View/Sysinfo .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\JsonApiView` view class is meant for generating JSON:API compliant output. For generic/custom JSON you can use the `Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\JsonView` class instead.

Comment: Is more tricky than that I think. I was trying get it done, and not work so far. Even when all is working (the controller connect with the view....etc) the result is a empty array []. Also, the headers output still `application/vnd.api+json` not matter what you try to change to the Document in the JsonView....